# NameError: name 'result' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a very simple program in python

```
 for i in range(1,1000):
     if (i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0) :
           result += i

 else:
      print('sum is {}'.format(result))
```

When I try to compile the problem I am getting the error.

```
NameError: name 'result' is not defined
```

Comment: Where do you believe you've defined `result`? If you want it to start with `0`, you'll have to be explicit about that and add the line `result = 0` at the beginning

Comment: Also, if you're doing Euler (or similar), then you want a results count that's divisible by three **or** five...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement:

```
result += i
```

is equivalent to:

```
result = result + i
```

But, the first time this statement is reached in your loop, the variable `result` has not been defined, so the right-hand-side of that assignment statement does not evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

Add `result = 0` before your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your indentation is inconsistent and incorrect which makes it harder to read.

```
result = 0
for i in range(1,1000):
    if (i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0) :
        result += i
    else:
        print 'sum is ',result
```

This is the way to get around your error, but I don't think this is actually what you're trying to do.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

or...

```
try: 
    result += i
except:
    result = i
```

but this won't get you past what happens if the loop condition never occurs (you would need another try in your printout), so just setting it prior to the loop is probably better.